# Flutter align items in row

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do create this layout.
[image]

But my texts are changes so their sizes are changing. So my layout turns like to this
[image]

or this [image]

But their sizes should be constant. How can I do this? I used flexible but it's not working or I may have used it wrong. Also I tried main axis alignment. **I wrapped progress bar with flexible** cause it doesn't have width or height and I can't give constant width. So when texts are changed it's space increasing or decreasing so it's view changes. This is the problem but I could't find any solution. Can anybody help?

Here is some code snippet:

```
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        child: Icon(
                      
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                        }),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                          valueListenable: _videoController,
                          builder: (context, VideoPlayerValue value, child) {
                            .....
                          
                            return Text(
                              videoControllerPosition,
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                              valueListenable: _videoController,
                              builder:
                                  (context, VideoPlayerValue value, child) {
                                return ProgressBar(
                                  ....
        
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
                      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: _videoController,
                        builder: (context, VideoPlayerValue value, child) {

                         ......
                          return Text(
                            bufferedTime,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: can you add your code snippet?

Comment: I added my code snippet as pseudo

Comment: @bss do you solve it?

Comment: No I didn't but I used a package doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Text` widget in `Container` and give `width` to it.
Then you can also wrap `Text` in `FittedBox` so the text fits into `Container`.

Comment: I thought it but don't want to give constant width to my widgets. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can also use `Expanded` and give every widget `flex`, so it looks the same on every device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flex property to achive your layout like this,

```
 Row(
             children: [
               Expanded(
                 flex: 2,
                 child: Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                   color: Colors.grey,
                   child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(width: 10,),
               Expanded(
                 flex: 2,
                 child: Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 14),
                   color: Colors.grey,
                   child: Text("Test"),
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(width: 10,),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child:  Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 14),
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Text("Progress bar"),
              ),),
               SizedBox(width: 10,),
               Expanded(
                 child: Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, bottom: 14),
                   color: Colors.grey,
                   child: Text("Test"),
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(width: 10,),
               Expanded(
                 child: Container(
                   alignment: Alignment.center,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                   color: Colors.grey,
                   child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with listTile and use spacer for flexible width

```
ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.person),
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Text("text", textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                Spacer(),
                Text("ProgressBar"),
                Spacer(),
                Expanded(child: Text("text",textAlign: TextAlign.end)),
              ],
            ),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
          ),
```

Output:

[image]